# Executing a PHP page after search + replacing keywords for language translation in the HTML

Tags: php, localization

I am translating my website into different languages and I have over 130 pages so i want to pass my .php files through a function that will replace keywords 
IE: Accessories = อุปกรณ์
Which is English to Thai.

I can get it to work using my method however... I have php (obviously) in these pages, and the output only displays the html and not executing the php

Is there a header method or something I have to pass at the start of my php pages..

here is the function I'm using to find text results and then replace them from my php files..

```
    <?php

    // lang.php
    function get_lang($file)
    {

    // Include a language file
        include 'lang_thai.php';

    // Get the data from the HTML
        $html = file_get_contents($file);

    // Create an empty array for the language variables

        $vars = array();

    // Scroll through each variable

        foreach($lang as $key => $value)

        {

            // Finds the array results in my lang_thai.php file (listed below)

            $vars[$key] = $value;
        }


    // Finally convert the strings

        $html = strtr($html, $vars);

    // Return the data


        echo $html;

    }

    ?>
```

//This is the lang_thai.php file

```
    <?php

    $lang = array(
    'Hot Items' => 'รายการสินค้า', 
    'Accessories' => 'อุปกรณ์'

    );


    ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should generate your entire HTML page and capture it with the output buffer `ob_start()` and then run your string replace method on that?  What you would need to do is start your PHP files with `ob_start()` and then end it with `$html = ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()`.  Just avoid replacing tags.  Regardless, I think this method will have performance issues as well as the trouble of bugs.  Maybe you could utilize the Zend_Translate class for your project instead?

Comment: I think, you should better use some templating system to reference all strings as variables (IDs) in PHP pages, and have separate string arrays for each language, accessible by the IDs. There is no need to look through entire page every time and to substitute strings within it in cycle. This is highly ineffective.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you both for your replies. 

@Stan: I already thought about declaring a bajillion variables for all the things i want translated and get the input from the user what language they want to display via a session variable or something. but just didn't want to edit several parts of the 130+ parts of the web pages i need translated. but i guess if its faster and more secure this will be a viable option and worth my time..

Comment: @jmbertucci: i like this idea and have seen some exmaples but had trouble getting it to work, i will research a little more and see if this will work.. so basically i just output what the php would normally appear in the browser using ob_start() and then assigning $html = ob_get_contents() and then passing the $html and then outputting that result ... i will try this now..

Comment: Why do you need to replace anything? The easiest way would be to reference each array value using the English key, and dependent upon the language selected, load in the respective language file.

Comment: @trickyzter, so i have to go through all my pages and assign array keys for each piece of information i want translated ?, thought translating the total outputting searching for keywords would save time and actually be more effective.

Comment: I'm not sure replacing the keywords within the document scope would be accurate (as mentioned by @jmbertucci), but it's entirely up to you.

Comment: ok guys, im biting the bullet on this, and going to reformat my pages which will translate variables on a session variable which will determine english, thai etc.. or what language i choose from a lang_languagename.php file which i will include on given session variable.. sound good ?

Comment: @JeffreyHolmes You mention you have over 100 files, is there any explanation to how these are structured?  Perhaps there's some more ideas we can help with to make this easier.

Comment: Well. I made these pages basically because i have a Menu which is made from DHTML menu program, so i created the links in reference to the pages. products_belts.php, products_shirts.php.. etc...
So most of these pages are just pages that have different sql queries.

Comment: Ok i was able to succeed in completing this the way i thought i could along with help from Jmbertucci's idea of the ob_start() and then ob_end)flush() is what i ended up using..

<?php
include('lang.php');
ob_start("get_lang");

include('index.php');
ob_end_flush();
?>

Comment: using this method, my lang files arrays look for string that have a marker or a key like this '{Hot Items}' => 'รายการสินค้า',.... so my words i want to translate i will edit the page words and replace them with a curly bracket... then  i can change all these words according to the array.

Comment: Update: i got the code working, but tags are being messed up due to the keywords im using. so im thinking 2 options..
find the letter before the tag and check if its a directory by seeing if that letter is a \, or the letter after it is a \.. how can i do this in PHP ? 
if ((strpos($lang[$key])) - 1 == '\\'){
  }
  else if ((strpos($lang[$key])) - 1 == ' '){
  }
  else {
   $vars[$key] = $value;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of frameworks use a function to translate as it goes instead of replacing after the fact using .pot files.  The function would look like this:

```
<h1><?php echo _('Hello, World') ?>!</h1>
```

So if it was English and not translated that function would just return the string untranslated.  If it was to be translated then it would return the translated string.

If you want to continue with your route which is definitely faster to implement try this:

```
<?php
    function translate($buffer) {
        $translation = include ('lang_tai.php');

        $keys = array_keys($translation);
        $vals = array_values($translation);

        return str_replace($keys, $vals, $buffer);
    }

    ob_start('translate');

    // ... all of your html stuff
```

Your language file is:

```
<?php
    return array(
        'Hot Items' => 'รายการสินค้า', 
        'Accessories' => 'อุปกรณ์'
    );
```

One cool thing is `include` can return values! So this is a good way to pass values from a file.  Also the ob_start is an output buffer with a callback. So what happens is after you echo all of your html to the screen, right before it actually displays to the screen it passes all of that data to the `translate` function and we then translate all of the data!